# Find all substrings of a string - StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, algorithm, indexoutofboundsexception, substring

I created class Word. Word has a constructor that takes a string argument and one method getSubstrings which returns a String containing all substring of word, sorted by length.

For example, if the user provides the input "rum", the method returns a
string that will print like this:

```
r
u
m
ru
um
rum
```

I want to concatenate the substrings in a String, separating them with a newline ("\n"). Then return the string.

**Code:**

```
    public class Word {
    String word;

    public Word(String word) {
        this.word = word;
    }
    /**
     * Gets all the substrings of this Word.
     * @return all substrings of this Word separated by newline
     */

    public String getSubstrings()
    {
        String str = "";
        int i, j;
        for (i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < word.length(); j++) {
                str = word.substring(i, i + j);
                str += "\n";
            }
        }
        return str;
    }
```

But it throws exception:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
    at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1911)
```

I stuck at this point. Maybe, you have other suggestions according this method signature `public String getSubstrings()`.
How to solve this issue?

Comment: If you use the `substring()` method inside a loop with a number of iterations i.e the method is likely to be invoked many times, then consider using the String constructor along with the `substring()` method like in your case, `str = new String(word.substring(i, i + j));`. Otherwise, it may cause a memory leak at a certain time (Yes, it is  unrelated to the concrete problem though).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Analysis of Exception:**

From [Java7 Docs of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.html)

```
public class StringIndexOutOfBoundsException extends IndexOutOfBoundsException
```

> Thrown by String methods to indicate that an index is either negative or **greater than the size of the string**.

From [Java 7 Docs of substring](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#substring%28int,%20int%29)

```
public String substring(int beginIndex,int endIndex)
```

> Returns a new string that is a substring of this string. The substring begins at the specified beginIndex and extends to the character at index endIndex - 1. Thus the length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex.

I guess this:  **length of the substring is endIndex-beginIndex** comes into `String index out of range: -1`. I have tested with multiple cases holding my assumption true but appreciate any other proof.

For -1:  `"rum".substring(2,1);` will give you `String index out of range: -1`

```
Parameters:
    beginIndex - the beginning index, inclusive.
    endIndex - the ending index, exclusive.
```

**Cause of StringIndexOutOfBoundsException**:

In the given code snippet, `substring` is trying to fetch string which has `endIndex` more than the total length of String (`i+j` will exceed the total length of string):

```
str = word.substring(i, i + j);
```

Consider the case when i=2 and j=2 for word "rum"

then `str=word.substring(2, 4);`
would not be possible

**Solution similar to code snippet given in Question:**

This should solve the problem:

```
 public String getSubstrings()
    {
        String str="",substr = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < word.length(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; i+j <= word.length(); j++) { //added i+j and equal to comparison
               substr = word.substring(j, i + j); //changed word.substring(i, i + j) to word.substring(j, i + j)
               if("".equals(substr))continue; //removing empty substrings
               str += substr; //added concatenation + operation
               str += "\n";
            }
        }
        return str+word;
    }
```

**Test Case:**

For `word="rum"`, this will give output:

```
r
u
m
ru
um
rum
```

Comment: it's because `str` gets overwritten on the internal loop from `=`. change it to `+=`

Comment: @nazar_art: Check now the output...It is perfect :)

Comment: @ritesh not exactly it givs: `r
ru
rum

u
um

m` But correct is: `r
u
m
ru
um
rum `

Comment: @nazar_art: now try this :)

Comment: @ritesh Now output is: `r
ru
rum
u
um
m` It's work yes but it isn't exactly correct output: `r u m ru um rum`

Comment: @nazar_art: No nazar: output is `r u m ru um rum` stright from my eclipse...you have not copied code correctly, I guess.

Comment: @ritesh just looking at your code via inspection, the output is wrong. As it loops through all the letters, it will print out all substrings starting with that letter before moving onto the next single letter. What you should be doing is having the outer loop control the length of the substring, and the inner loop control the first letter.

Comment: @ardentsonata: It is giving the output as mentioned in answer. I have tested it on eclipse. And I guess my outer loop control the length of the substring, and the inner loop control the first letter. I am sorry, If I have not understood you properly. There could be many better ways to do it, I am not arguing about it.

Comment: @ritesh - hmm I guess I misread it the first time, it looks correct now. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 4):

Your logic seems convoluted , the source of exception:

```
str = word.substring(i, i + j);
```

Consider your `i` and `j` both equals `word.length()-1` , then the `substring()` will fail.

You can simply do :

```
public String getSubstrings(String word){
   StringBuilder sub= new StringBuilder();
   for( int i = 0 ; i < word.length() ; i++ )
   {
      for( int j = 1 ; j <= word.length() - i ; j++ )
      {
         sub .append(word.substring(i, i+j)).append("\n");
      }
   }
   return sub.toString();
}
```

**Note:** Consider using [`StringBuilder`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) instead of `String` if you will do lots of concatenation on `String`.

Comment: @nazar_art can you share me the test results ?

Comment: You can't change signature of method `public String getSubstrings()`

Answer (score 1):

I realize I'm a little late to this party, and I'm a very new programmer, myself -- but I was running into the same error last night while trying to write a similar method.

For me, it helped to rename the counter variables of the nested `for` loops to names that described what they are keeping track of. For the outer loop, I used `int subLength`, and for the inner loop, I used `int position` (starting position). I'm sure there are other ways of doing this, but I was happy with my solution. Here is some pseudocode that I hope will help someone else who looks this question up:

```
     for each possible substring length 1 up to and including the original word length: 
            generate substrings starting at the 0th position, and then starting at each 
            proceeding letter up to but not including (word.length() - (subLength - 1))
```